# Como encontrar el mayor y menor Precio/Modelo en un Array

Tags: java, array

Les consulto, porque estoy queriendo resolver un ejercicio, donde me pide el mayor y menor precio de un array de 4 posiciones de vehículos (2 autos y 2 motos), pero el problema que tengo, es que tengo que agregar el modelo (junto obviamente al precio). Es decir, no tengo problema para que me indique el valor mas alto, el problema se me da cuando tengo que incluir el precio y el modelo!

Como puedo hacer? Me dan una mano? Gracias!

Por ejemplo:
El vehiculo mas caro es el Peugeot 208
El vehiculo mas economico es la Honda Titan

```
public class EntrevistaVehiculos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Vehiculos arrayVehiculos[]=new Vehiculos[4];

        arrayVehiculos[0]=new Automoviles("Peugeot", "206", 4, 200000);

        arrayVehiculos[1]=new Motos("Honda", "Titan", 125, 60000);

        arrayVehiculos[2]=new Automoviles("Peugeot", "208", 5, 250000);

        arrayVehiculos[3]=new Motos("Yamaha", "YBR", 160, 80500.50);


        for(Vehiculos e:arrayVehiculos) {           

            System.out.println("Marca: " + e.getMarca() + " // " + " Modelo: " + e.getModelo() +  " // " + e.caracteristica() + " // " + " Precio: " + e.getPrecio()); 

        }

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Vehiculo Mas Caro vs Mas Economico");


        System.out.println();


        System.out.println("Vehículos ordenados por precio de mayor a menor:");

        Arrays.sort(arrayVehiculos);

        for(Vehiculos e:arrayVehiculos) {           

            System.out.println("Marca: " + e.getMarca() + " // " + " Modelo: " + e.getModelo()); 

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Agrega las partes esenciales para que compile para tener un [mcve] o la respuesta será teórica y no código que realmente funcione

Comment: necesitas usar el método java.util.Arrays.sort(vehiculos, Comparator c). E implementar los diferentes comparadores que requieras.

Comment: Hola @AlbertoLopez, me darias una mano como implementarias ese metodo sort con el Comparator? No lo estoy pudiendo hacer para que el array solo me arroje en consola el vehiculo de mayor y menor precio (y con el modelo). Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Te pongo un par de ejemplos.

```
//aquí estoy asumiendo que el precio viene es tipo java.lang.Double
//pero lo puedes cambiar según el tipo que uses.
    java.util.Comparator<Vehiculo> comparadorDePrecios =
      new java.util.Comparator() {
          public int compare(Object v1, Object v2) {
              double precio1 = ((Vehiculo)v1).precio();
              double precio2 = ((Vehiculo)v2).precio();
              return Double.compare(precio1, precio2);
         }
      };


    java.util.Comparator<Vehiculo> comparadorDeModelos =
        new java.util.Comparator() {
          public int compare(Object v1, Object v2) {
              String modelo1 = ((Vehiculo)v1).modelo();
              String modelo2 = ((Vehiculo)v2).modelo();
              return modelo1.compareTo(modelo2);
         }
      };
```

Entonces puedes usar alguno en el array.sort dependiendo de cual quieras.

```
Arrays.sort(arrayVehiculos, comparadorDePrecios);
```

ó

```
Arrays.sort(arrayVehiculos, comparadorDeModelos);
```

O puedes agregar n comparadores dependiendo de lo que requieras.

Comment: Esto es lo que buscaba!  Solucionado

Comment: No lo había probado y tenía varios errores de sintaxis, pero ya lo cambié. Saludos.

Comment: Si, pero cambie los parametros y funciono perfecto! Mil gracias @AlbertoLopez

Answer (score 0):

La clase Vehículo debe implementar la Interface Comparable, por ejemplo,

```
 package stack;

public abstract class Vehiculo implements Comparable<Vehiculo> {

    private String marca;
    private String modelo;
    private String caracteristica;
    private int precio;

    public abstract void tipo();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vehiculo [marca=" + marca + ", modelo=" + modelo + ", caracteristica=" + caracteristica + ", precio="
                + precio + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Vehiculo o) {
        if (precio < o.precio) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (precio > o.precio) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }


    public Vehiculo() {

    }

    public Vehiculo(String marca, String modelo, String caracteristica, int precio) {
        this.marca = marca;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.caracteristica = caracteristica;
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }

    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(String modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    public String getCaracteristica() {
        return caracteristica;
    }

    public void setCaracteristica(String caracteristica) {
        this.caracteristica = caracteristica;
    }

    public int getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(int precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }



}
```

Después creas las clases Moto y Automóvil que heredan de Vehículo y ya los puedes ordenar con el método `sort`. La clave está en implementar la Interface Comparable y eso te obliga a sobrescribir el método `compareTo`. Fíjate bien en como se implementa este método, ahí está la clave.
Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Hola @oscar! Ya lo hice eso, pude ordenar el array de mayor a menor precio, pero lo que no puedo hacer es que la aplicacion solo me muestre en consola por medio de un algoritmo el vehiculo de mayor valor y el de menor valor (esos 2 unicamente). Creo que va por el lado de lo que dice @AlbertoLopez con la clase Arrays y Comparator, pero no se implementarla!

Comment: Pero si ya lo tienes ordenado, el de menor valor va a ser el primer objeto de la lista y el de mayor valor el último, los quitas del array y los imprimes o haces lo que tengas que hacer con ellos.

Comment: Hola @oscar! Si, lo pense, pero todos los datos los tengo que pasar por un algoritmo, y encima en ese orden. Es decir, primero el array completo desordenado, segundo el vehiculo mas caro y mas barato, y por ultimo el orden de mas caro a mas barato de todos. Es un ejercicio, todo el dia de hoy estoy con esto, jaja

Comment: Definición de algoritmo "Conjunto ordenado de operaciones sistemáticas que permite hacer un cálculo y hallar la solución de un tipo de problemas." 1º operación, ordenar el array. 2ª, imprimir el mas caro y el mas barato y 3ª en orden del mas caro al mas barato". No entiendo por qué no te vale, a lo mejor no estoy entendiendo el ejercicio, en cualquier caso que tengas suerte!!

Comment: No te preocupes @oscar! Son esos ejercicios en el cual el profesor quiere que estes todo el dia con puntos que te dan vuelta la cabeza. Gracias igual!!!

Comment: lo mas probable es que tengas razon @oscar, ya que soy hiper junior en esto, y me hago lio, lo que si puedo decirte es GRACIAS por tu esfuerzo, gracias a ti, gente como yo aprende cada dia mas. Me dijieron que en este mundo de la programacion, se aprende mas cuando te equivocas a cuando asertas, y por esa razón me equivoco demasiado, aunque es porque tambien soy muy bruto :) . Abrazo amigo!

Comment: Gracias Gonzalo, un abrazo y no te desanimes que ya tienes muy cerca la solución.